# Maximizing a function subject to a constraint

Tags: calculus, optimization, systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

I need help to find the maximum ($x^∗, y^∗, z^∗$) of the production function
$Q(x, y, z) = x^{1/4}y^{1/4}z^{1/4}$

subject to the budget constraint $h(x, y, z) = ax+by +cz −d = 0$, (where $a, b, c, d$ are positive constants), in terms of these constants. And from this, I must find an expression for the maximum value $Q^∗$ of the budget in terms of $a, b, c, d$ and the corresponding value $λ^∗$ of the Lagrange multiplier.

So far in this question I have set up a system of linear equations from the partial derivatives of the Lagrangian form:

$L_x = \dfrac{1}{4}y^{1/4}z^{1/4}y^{-3/4} - a\lambda = 0$

$L_y = \dfrac{1}{4}x^{1/4}z^{1/4}x^{-3/4} - b\lambda = 0$

$L_z = \dfrac{1}{4}x^{1/4}y^{1/4}z^{-3/4} - c\lambda = 0$

$-L_\lambda = ax + by +cz -d = 0$

From here I have trouble solving these equations and taking the question to the next step.

Comment: Are you sure that is $$ax+by+cz-d=0$$ and not $$ax+by+cz+d=0$$ instead?

Comment: Yes I am sure. The original equation is $ax +by + cz = d$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lagrangian relaxation can be written as 
$$
\text{Maximize } L(\lambda) = (xyz)^{1/4} + \lambda(d - ax - by - cz) \\
\lambda \geq 0
$$
Partially differentiating with respect to each variable, we get 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = \frac{(yz)^{1/4}}{4x^{3/4}}-a\lambda = 0  \tag 1\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = \frac{(xz)^{1/4}}{4y^{3/4}}-b\lambda = 0  \tag 2\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial z} = \frac{(xy)^{1/4}}{4z^{3/4}}-c\lambda = 0  \tag 3\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = ax + by + cz - d = 0 \tag 4
\end{align}

Solving equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $ax = by$ and solving equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get $by = cz$. Once we know this, we can find out the optimal values are

$$
x^* = \frac{d}{3a} \\
y^* = \frac{d}{3b} \\
z^* = \frac{d}{3c} \\
\lambda^* = \Big(\frac{3}{abcd}\Big)^{1/4} \\ 
$$